# Jquery post returns object object

Tags: jquery

I am trying to submit an array of checkboxes to a php document. Strangly it sends [object object] instead of the values.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input:checkbox').change(function() {
 var Day = $(this).closest('div.cat').attr("id");
 var category= $('#'+Day+' input[type=checkbox]:checked').serializeArray();
 $.post("savedaily.php", { "cat[]": category, day: Day })
   .done(function(data) {
   alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
 });

 });
});
```

Comment: What is `savedaily.php`?

Comment: Short answer is these two $day = $_POST['day'];
$cat = $_POST['cat']; which then is saved to the DB (each $cat is updated where = $day)

Comment: Yeah? I can tell you that it works like planned with the normal submit function. And day -> $day works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

When you have to exchange objects using ajax you should think about **serialization**, and I recomand you to:

1. json encode the object in jQuery before sending it to PHP side
2. In php you will get the object in a string format, then you need to json decoded to get your object back
3. I'm not sure if its a good idea to exchange object, may be you will need to think about exchanging table instead!